# Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void MainActivity$Send.write(byte[])' on a null object reference

Tags: java, android, android-studio

try to send 1 onclick of button to my Arduino form app. But my application gets crash when I click on button can any one help me to get out of this.I just started with android studio so not having much idea about it.and cant able to get the solution for this error.
thanks  in advance :).

main activity

```
     package com.example.dataexample;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothServerSocket;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.nfc.Tag;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.sql.ClientInfoStatus;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.UUID;
import java.net.*;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    static final UUID mUUID = UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB");
    Button bt1,bt2;

    Button button;
    ListView lv;
    BluetoothAdapter bluetoothAdapter;
    Clinetclass clinetclass;
    Send sendReceive = new Send(clinetclass.getSocket());
    BluetoothDevice[] btarray;







    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        button=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        lv=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv);
        bluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
        bt1=(Button) findViewById(R.id.ON);

        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Clinetclass clinetclass=new Clinetclass(btarray[position]);
                clinetclass.start();

                //openactivity2();
            }


        });
        bt1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(sendReceive == null)
                    return;
                    String stron="49";
                    sendReceive.write(stron.getBytes());
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"turned ON",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });

    }

    private class Clinetclass extends Thread
    {
        private BluetoothDevice device;
        private BluetoothSocket socket;
        public BluetoothSocket getSocket() {
            return socket;
        }

        public Clinetclass(BluetoothDevice device1)
        {
            this.device=device1;

            try {
                socket=device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(mUUID);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        public void run()
        {
            try {
                socket.connect();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    private static class Send extends Thread
    {
        private final BluetoothSocket bluetoothSocket;
        private final OutputStream outputStream;

        public Send (BluetoothSocket socket)
        {
            bluetoothSocket=socket;
            OutputStream tempOut=null;

            try {
                tempOut=bluetoothSocket.getOutputStream();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            outputStream=tempOut;
        }
        public void write(byte[] bytes)
        {
            try {
                outputStream.write(bytes);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }

    public void list(View v) {


        Set<BluetoothDevice> bt=bluetoothAdapter.getBondedDevices();
        String[] strings=new String[bt.size()];
        btarray=new BluetoothDevice[bt.size()];
        int index=0;

        if( bt.size()>0) {
            for (BluetoothDevice device : bt) {
                btarray[index] = device;
                strings[index] = device.getName();
                index++;
            }
            ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, strings);
            lv.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
        }
    }

}
```

logcat

```
Process: com.example.dataexample, PID: 25405
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.example.dataexample.MainActivity$Send.write(byte[])' on a null object reference
        at com.example.dataexample.MainActivity$2.onClick(MainActivity.java:67)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7261)
        at com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton.performClick(MaterialButton.java:1194)
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7223)
        at android.view.View.access$3800(View.java:824)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:27721)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:238)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7824)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:981)
```

Comment: if (sendReceive==null) return;

Answer (score 0):

In on click you are calling

```java
sendReceive.write(stron.getBytes());
```

this fails because sendReceive is never initialized.

You could do this by writing

```java
sendReceive = new Send(clinetclass.getSocket());
```

after the clinetclass is started.
(when you call `clinetclass.start();`)

This requires you to create a getter method for the socket in Clinetclass (which returns socket).

In Clinetclass:

```java
public BluetoothSocket getSocket() {
    return socket;
}
```

Also you should add `if (sendReceive == null) return;` before writing, to not get an error if you haven't clicked the ListView before (like blackapps commented).

Comment: thnaks but can u tell me how can I initialize it ?

Comment: 'Send sendReceive = new Send(clinetclass.getSocket());'  not allowing getspocket.

Comment: @jeevanpatil you need to add the getter method

Comment: ohk so I did what u said and now my app crash before it starts ill update the code just have a look

Comment: you have to put the `sendReceive = new Send(clinetclass.getSocket());` directly after you call `clinetclass.start();`

Comment: ohk now its working